# How to set a twitter welcome message with newlines, emojis, urls via twirl

Tags: json, curl, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm exploring the twitter API for the first time through twurl on my Mac. I've been able to successfully set a welcome message, set the rule, delete and replace etc. However, I'm having an issue with setting a direct message that features newlines.

I've tried pasting the plaintext into the message text value, I've used https://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html to convert the message to JSON format, but twurl would not accept either of these.

```
    twurl -A 'Content-type: application/json' /1.1/direct_messages/welcome_messages/new.json -d '{"name": "auto welcome", welcome_message": {"message_data": {"text": "This is a welcome message.\n\nAnd I display accross multiple lines.\n\nHere's an emoji!  \uD83D\uDC4A"}}}'
```

The terminal returns nothing, which seems to be the behaviour when the input was not accepted.

I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious, I'll be greatly appreciative of any assistance that can be provided

Comment: Do you already know the answer?